# AWS : How to troubleshoot unhealthy registered target in target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I setup my network load balancer and target group. 
I associated master node private IP from my running instance to this new target group and registered there.

It started with the 'initial' status and then after 5 mins, it turns to 'unhealthy' status.
I am not able to find out why 'Health checks failed'. What stop the health check to be successful?

I am using AWS GUI, not too much familiar with CLI. pls assist.

More Info---

Health check settings are:
 Protocol = HTTP
 Path = /
rest all defaults

Target group as follows: 
Target type = ip
Protocol : Port = TCP : 8998

master node private IP is within the vpc and subnet

Comment: What SGs do you have on the instance(s)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. it got resolved. we need to add rules for LB to talk to master node SG

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. If you don't mind, I will add an answer as this was SG issue as I suspected for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was with **incorrectly set security groups** on the instances.

The **solution** was to allow incoming traffic from the security group of the load balancer.